# Dock - app name instead of icons?

Tags: macos, dock

Is there a way to hide the icons in the dock and just show text of the app name instead?

Comment: This is so utterly counter to the "Apple Spirit" that I would be shocked if the answer were anything other than no, but I don't have a canonical answer (yet).

Comment: Okay, Steve Jobs. Settle down, its a simple question. I just don't want icons in my dock.

Comment: I'm not saying it wouldn't be a cool feature; I'm just saying I'd be shocked if there were an option to do that, short of changing all the icons to pictures of the text of the program name.

Comment: Okay thats actually possible, but how do I disable the text that pops up when you hover over an app on the dock?

Comment: @JackStewart What would be the utility of the Dock without icons? You'd be stuck reading all the app names to find anything.

Comment: It's in an OSX partition on my hard drive that I only use a few different apps with.

Comment: As an unconventional alternative, if you just don't like the Dock's use of screen real estate, you could hide it entirely and use Spotlight, Launch Pad, or a 3rd-party app like Launchbar or Alfred to launch your apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was curious about what you wanted, but you can't just have "Text" instead of icons, but you can have icons that are "text" :)

check out this link on how one user solved his issue.

http://arctictransfuse.deviantart.com/art/Gill-Sans-Text-Dock-Icons-154466636

the download link is over on the right side.

how to change your icons in OSX http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2493

i think this is what you were going after...

Comment: thanks a bunch. I'll try that, do you know if there is a way I can remove the hover text that pops up when the mouse hovers over an app?

Comment: You could use candy bar to change the icons, and as an extra special super bonus it's now free http://www.panic.com/blog/2012/08/candybar-mountain-lion-and-beyond/

Comment: yeah I just saw that, but I haven't found a way to get rid of just the text that hovers around... :-\

Comment: There is a way to hide the text that appears on hover for at least the common apps explained in the answers to this question: [Hide App Name in Mac OS X Lion Dock](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57300/hide-app-name-in-mac-os-x-lion-dock)